# Assign different php value after every click

Tags: javascript, php

I know this is a hack, but I really need it.

I have following code:

```
<thead>
   <?php 
     if(isset($_COOKIE['gautasId'])) {
      $wishes = $conn->query("SELECT sa.id, sa.aprasymas, sa.poreikiai, sa.miestas, s.statusas FROM svajoniu_aprasymas sa join svajoniu_statusai s on s.id = sa.statusas where sa.senolio_id = " . $_COOKIE['gautasId']);
     }                     
     if ($wishes->num_rows == 0) {
     ?>
     <tr>
        <th>No data</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
   <?php } else { ?>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>...</th>
            <th>...</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
```

I set that cookie value:

```
echo "<tr><td><span onclick=setValue('$eldId') class='fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw'></span> </span></td>";
```

```
function setValue(id) {
  document.cookie = "gautasId = " + id;
}
```

and this function is hit everytime I click it, but query values do not change.
Is it possible to do this somehow?

Comment: PHP runs on the server so you would need to make an http request back to the server. So means you have to refresh the page, submit a form, make a Ajax call, make a fetch call, etc

Comment: *"but query values do not change"* - How specifically are you observing that?  What triggers this page to load again and fetch new data?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty awfull code, so, consider removing the JavaScript element entirely by changing $_COOKIE to $_GET, and adding the ID to the url using a href tag.

echo "<a href=‘?id=$eldId' class='fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw'> ";

Then use $_GET[id] to pickup the value from the url

Comment: will `$_GET` solve this problem if changes are done for same page? I am not very familiar with PHP so not sure how it works

Comment: Updated answer with example code

Comment: hmmm but there's no way to prevent reloading, right?

Comment: Not without Ajax